# How do I make text wibbly wobbly with animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

Only, I wish to learn using Animation Nodes for future motion graphics. Any assistance is appreciated. 
You can do your own way of wobbling the text. I am not too exact as to how do you do it or what font style you use. I am only just keen on learning nodes for wobbling text for future projects. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is "wibbly wobbly"? Can you share some reference? The blend file has no packed resources, you should add those directly in the question.

Comment: I just uploaded Blend file so that you can see video of animated text that I did in Moho Pro.

Comment: I tried to upload a video here, but I find it difficult to do so.

Comment: The blend file you provided has no packed resources, thus we can't view the video. You can use a service such as [ezgif](https://ezgif.com/maker) to convert your videos to gifs and upload them here. Alternatively, use the imgur video to gif service, get the direct link, change the extension to gif from gifv and copy it to the stackexchange uploader.

Comment: I returned to Moho Pro and exported video to Gif. I have uploaded the gif above. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters follow the path of a sine-like function, so we should position and animate on a sine wave. We will be using the same technique described in this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122407/how-to-do-kinetic-text-with-animation-nodes/122421#122421). The y position of each character should be the sine of its x position, which is trivial to do. To orient the characters along the sine wave, we will compute the angle that that the curve makes with the x axis by computing the arctangent of the derivative of the sine function $\arctan(\frac{d \sin(t)}{dt}) = \arctan(\cos(t))$:

[image: Sine Wave]

We can change the frequency by multiplying by $f$ and the amplitude by multiplying by $\alpha$ to have the function $\alpha\sin(ft)$ which has an angle $\arctan(\frac{d(\alpha\sin(ft))}{dt}) = \arctan(\alpha f \cos(ft))$:

[image: Frequency]

Lets animate the scale and the start value of the progression to get:

[image: Animate]

Finally, lets animate the y position of the characters such that it becomes zero at the end of the animation. We can do this by multiplying by the inverse of a sharp exponential interpolation:

[image: Exponential Interpolation]

This concludes the first effect. To achieve the second effect, try adding a noise vector to the locations of the characters:

[image: Wiggle]

Fine tune the amplitude and speed to get the feel you are after.

Comment: This is wonderful and you are a star. Many thanks.