# Delay Action Node

Tags: animation-nodes

I have seen it used for instance here but cannot (yet) find it in the animation nodes manual

[How to Do Kinetic Text with Animation Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122407/how-to-do-kinetic-text-with-animation-nodes)

Where do I find this node?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These nodes were added later, that is why they are not mentioned in the manual. There are two ways to find any node:

1. Press **Ctrl+A** then a search-menu will appear, type the name of the node:
   [image]
2. Press **Shift+A** or click on **add** option in the header then a nodes-menu appear where you can find the required nodes:

   [image]

Comment: Aha, I thought as much, thanks. Do you know if these and the other recently added nodes will be added to the manual? I was trying to work my way through it and would like to not miss stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know when these nodes will be added to the manual. However, you can ask this on Github-Animation Nodes: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues